# Deleting missing values

Tags: stata

I'm trying to clean my panel data set in Stata, which includes data on GDP growth rates for different countries over 5 years. I would like to delete all rows, which have missing values (denoted as `..` in the data set). Each row has an id (`gene row_id = _n`). For example, if I want to delete all missing values of the variable `YR2013`, I use the code: `drop if YR2013==.` and the error message `type mismatch` appears. Can someone tell me how to delete the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type mismatch` message indicates that your variable is really string. That being so

```
drop if missing(real(YR2013)) 
destring YR2013, replace
```

is a way forward, as your variable will be no use otherwise.

A more general recipe is

```
destring *, ignore("..") replace
```